# Which countries taxes do I need to pay?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, self-employment, working-abroad, sweden

I have a question about paying business taxes after you move abroad. I currently own my own business as an online freelancer and work for an umbrella company who manage all my taxes. I'm going to move abroad in a few months and I was wondering at what point do I need to start paying taxes to the new country?

Once I relocate my bank account and contract with the umbrella company will still be active so if I acquired a new online contract, completed the work whilst living in that new country and then they paid it towards my current umbrella company would I be doing anything wrong? (since the taxes would be going towards the country I was previously living in and not the new one)

Updated - I currently live in the UK and will be moving to Sweden

Comment: What are the two countries involved? There’s no one-size-fits all answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The United Kingdom and Sweden have a tax agreement; [convention between the Kingdom of Sweden and the United Kingdom of Great Britain for the avoidance of double taxation and the prevention of fiscal evasion with respect to taxes on income and capital gains](https://www.regeringen.se/49bb0f/contentassets/a873afb40aa7468b8dbcc670b293ef1d/skatteavtal-mellan-sverige-samt-storbritannien-och-nordirland).

If you're moving permanently you will have to pay taxes in Sweden for all of your income. I'm unsure about the tax situation your "umbrella company" will find itself in. I'm guessing that you by "umbrella company" mean a company that takes care of taxes and VAT and stuff and just gives you a "salary". If that's the case, you should either consult their support, or simply switch to a Swedish one. I know of two; [CoolCompany](https://coolcompany.com/) and [Frilans Finans](https://www.frilansfinans.se/).

Comment: Full answer to this question would need to define treatment in the year of the move, with the key question being what happens to income earned in the year prior to the date of the move, what happens to the the remainder of the year, and whether that answer differs based on how late in the year the OP moved.